Blender File opening and Immediate close
I have a file that seems to open but then immediately closes when opening I don't know what's going on. At first, I created the file on my personal computer and it seemed to work. I was able to open it into another PC from our animation Lab but when I got home it opened and immediately closed... I need help to fix this

Which Blender versions are you using, is one of them newer or older than the others? Not the usual behaviour when opening a file of a different version, but this once happened to me. Opening with the correct version worked then.
